# Add data to row if it meets criteria, else ignore

Tags: google-sheets

I have raw data in my spreadsheet that comes from a Google Form that looks like the following:

```
    (Cost)      (Source)    (Frivolous) (Medium)    (Comments)
    A           B           C           D           E
1   15.94       McDonalds   Yes         Credit      was hungry
2   98.32       School      No          Check       Paid for textbooks
3   843.00      Hospital    No          Check       Surgery
4   0           asdff       Yes         N/A         Ignore this one woops   
5   
6   23.99       Dentist     No          Credit      Check up
```

I want this data to always be copied to a different sheet, but ONLY the data that matches a condition. That condition in this case is if `Frivolous` is `No`, meaning I only want on this separate page to track valid important spending.

My second page I want them to look like the following:

```
    (Cost)      (Source)    (Frivolous) (Medium)    (Comments)
    A           B           C           D           E
1   98.32       School      No          Check       Paid for textbooks
2   843.00      Hospital    No          Check       Surgery
3   23.99       Dentist     No          Credit      Check up
```

Notice how empty entries are ignored and also entries with `Yes` under `Frivolous` are ignored as well.

How would I achieve this? I have absolutely no idea how that would work since I've only been able to achieve this through `filter` which will not work for this.

Comment: So why doesn't Data ► AutoFilter work?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Google docs so I will need a formula based approach instead. The only option for `Filter` in Docs is a manual filter, which you would have to do every single time new data is put into the spreadsheet.

Comment: You've tagged your question [excel]. I'll retag it for you so you can receive a focused answer.

Comment: I understand but both platforms are extremely similar that it's rare that you ever find a disconnect between the two. Surely there is some sort of array formula that can do this, which would be perfect for an advanced excel user to answer?

Comment: Well, a conditional match to progressively show the first, second, third, etc matching record would just happen to be one of those times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say a few words in defense of Google Spreadsheets and show some great functions that will work, but they are not supported by [excel].

**Query**

First you may use simple query:

```
=QUERY(sheet1!A:E,"select * where C = 'No'")
```

This single short formula will give the desired result, there's no need to fill right and down.

**Filter**

Actually you may use `filter` too. This function seems to work too:

```
=FILTER(sheet1!A:E,sheet1!C:C="No")
```

---

Please, read more info about this functions:

1. [Filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
2. [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and full [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

You'll find many exciting things that could be done in Google spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks for the [google-sheets] specific followup Max.tbh, my own formula knowledge is way too xl-specific.

Comment: Unbelievable. You can do SQL commands in Google Docs? That's crazy. Thank you and @Jeeped so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was having some trouble with [google-sheets] ArrayFormula function so I used an old-school formula with [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) and [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in its array form. In A2,

```
=iferror(index(Sheet13!A$1:A$99, small(index(row($1:$99)+(Sheet13!$C$1:$C$99<>"no")*1E+99, 0, 0), row(1:1))), "")
```

Fill both right and down.

[image: nonfrivilous]

So you were in fact correct that this could be solved in [excel] with an identical solution as [google-spreadsheet]. However, there are superior methods in newer [exce] (2010+) using the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) that [google-spreadsheet] does not support and I'm sure that [google-sheets] has more elegant functions that I am not recalling right this moment.

Look to Sheet13 and Sheet14 [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zm67OStnh6UkHQgahQJzrMiy-umXQ1DRycf2wg-KUrs) for the working sample.

Comment: Wow that is one insane formula. What does the section `*1E+99` mean and what is its purpose? Also if you could allow entry into that Google Docs file, I would really appreciate it. So far this formula is outputting a `double` value in the cell that I place it in, but I'm guessing that my data is not perfectly lined up somehow.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zm67OStnh6UkHQgahQJzrMiy-umXQ1DRycf2wg-KUrs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Essentially you are passing a series of matching row numbers back to the outer index function. Any row that does not match column = "no" has a 1 followed by 99 zeroes added to its row number. That isn't the small of anything (and is actually an illegal row number). The row(1:1) on the right is passing 1, 2, 3, 4 etc to the small's k parameter as you fill down.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It works great. However, there is one problem. One of my columns is for the date of the transaction. For example `7/30/2016`. This formula interprets that on the new sheet as `42579`. I assume this is due to the `1E+99`? What can be done in this case?

Comment: `42579` is 28-Jul-2016. Just format the column in the date format you prefer.

Comment: Oh wow.... can you explain why 42579 represents 7/28/2016? How is a date converted into an integer like that?

Comment: A day is 1. A date is 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Today happens to be 42,582. Time is a decimal portion of a day. Today at noon will be 42,582.5 and today at 06:00 pm will be 42,582.75. A cell's value with a General cell format can carry a marker that tells Excel it is a date. Certain functions will inadvertently strip that marker leaving only the numerical value but you can replace the date with a Date cell format.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man. You are a god. I thought it would work as a hash function like in many programming languages but your explanation really reminds me of the concept of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Fun fact - Because Lotus was the premier (and generally de facto standard) spreadsheet program and they screwed up the year 1900 as a leap year (every 100 years, what would normally be a leap year isn't one) all spreadsheet programs including Excel have had to intentionally include the same mistake or they could not maintain cross-platform compatibility with Lotus. So due to Lotus' screw-up, all spreadsheet programs since have had a 29-Feb-1900 when there shouldn't actually be one.